# Groups of order $64$ with abelian group of automorphism

Tags: group-theory, p-groups

G. A. Miller in 1913 constructed the first example of a non-abelian group of order $64$ with abelian group of automorphisms. It is the group 
$$G=(C_8\rtimes C_4)\rtimes C_2=\langle x,y,z\colon x^8, y^4, z^2, yxy^{-1}=x^5, zxz^{-1}=x,zyz^{-1}=y^{-1}\rangle.$$
After few years, following observations were made:

1. There is no non-abelian group of order $<64$ with abelian group of automorphism.
2. There are (exactly) two more non-abelian group of order $64$ with abelian automorphism group.

**Question:** What are the other groups of order $64$ with abelian automorphism group? In the presentation, where they differs with $G$? (I mean, it may be a *slight* modification of $G$ above; if it is such, what is that modification?)

---

**Edit:** James pointed error; there are two more non-abelian groups of order $64$, *not one*, with abelian automorphism group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be quite correct.  There appear to be three non-abelian groups of order $64$ with abelian automorphism group.  They are:

```
SmallGroup( 64, 68 )
SmallGroup( 64, 69 )
SmallGroup( 64, 116 )
```

Miller's group is the last of these three.

EDIT: Assuming I haven't made any transcription errors here, a presentation for SmallGroup( 64, 68 ) is

$$\langle x,y,z \mid x^4, z^4, x^2 = y^2,
z^2 = [y,x],
[y,z],
[x, z^2],
[y, x^2],
[z, x^2],
[z,x] = [x^{-1},z]
\rangle.$$
A presentation for SmallGroup( 64, 69 ) is:

$$\langle x,y,z \mid x^4, z^4, y^2 = z^2 x^2,
z^2 = [y,x],
[z,y], [z,x],
[y,[z,x]],
[x^2, z], [x^2, y], [z^2, x],
[z,x] = [x, z^{-1}]\rangle.$$

Comment: I didn't have GAP system; I didn't get presentations of these groups online; it would be better if the presentation of first two is given.

Comment: You might to explore http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_64#Families_and_classification and the book of Marshall Hall and James Senior - The groups of order $2^n$, $n \leq 6$.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to use GAP. Or you could use the [Magma online calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) Type G := SmallGroup(64,68); FPGroup(G); to get a presentation on $6$ generators.

Comment: In presentation for (64,69) some relations may be ignored: since $[z,x]=1$ hence $[y,[z,x]]=1$, $[z^2,x]=1$, $[x^2,z]=1$, and $[z,x]=[x,z^{-1}]$ is obvious.

Comment: @pGroups Right. I forgot to simplify the other presentation.